# Allow free typing when manually inserting foreign keys into table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, innodb

Currently when inserting a record i can only select from a drop down menu when there is a foreign relation on the column. This will get frustrating when the list of foreign records grow, imagine scrolling to No 10.000. So is there any way to set this back to free typing and just give me an error if the value does not exist in the foreign table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but phpMyAdmin is not a data entry tool. You should create an application specific to your schema and needs if you need to enter a lot of data. phpMyAdmin is a very general purpose tool for light administration and data browsing.

Comment: Its just strange behaviour. I hacked my way around it by eliminating the foreign key, inserted a couple of dozen records and recreated the foreign key. It is just plain stupid you cannot free type inside the textbox once a foreign key has been created on that collumn.